# Javascript event after element is defined

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if I could avoid inserting a `<script>` tag in my HTML, and use events instead:

```
<div id="foo">
    <script>
       document.getElementById('foo').className = 'has-js';
       // ^^ can I put this in some on* attribute of #foo,
       // and make it run at this point ?
    </script>

    ...   
    <div ...
```

Is there some `on*` attribute I can use on the `#foo` div where I can insert my javascript?

Comment: What is it that you're ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: There's an event on initial load (not on IE, but jQuery can emulate that).

Comment: @lee, to adjust the class of the `#foo` div, as soon as possible

Comment: And you wish to adjust it after the element has been defined. Why?

Comment: You can have one single `<script>` tag in the `<head>` section and handle everything there. That also look prettier than inline coding.

Comment: because the initial class changes the appearance, and I don't want that to be visible for a short period of time (until the page loads)

Comment: Why not insert the correct class right away?

Comment: I think you're right in that the best way to go about this is to include a script tag directly under the div

Comment: So what is stopping you from serving HTML with the desired initial class to start with?

Comment: The fact that I don't know if the user has javascript enabled or not...

Comment: @JanDvorak: A `js` class isn’t uncommon?

Comment: <noscript>Times have changed. Enable javascript or you will miss out.</noscript>

Comment: @Alex you could add the class to `body`

Comment: `body.js #dynamic-menu {display: block}`

Comment: would help to explain full scenario, if you have access to the html, what difference does it make if user has js enabled or not? Question is too vague, thus all the comments

Comment: n.b.: I used `no-js` in my previous project. Most likely I'll start using `body.js` and `body.no-js` in tandem as my standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn’t. The most compact it can be is `<script>initSomething();</script>` where you want the event.

And if this isn’t some kind of plugin, try adding it to `<body>` instead. That’s the “standard”.

Comment: Mutation observers can't be used?

Comment: @JanDvorak not practically, no. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events#Cross-browser_support

Comment: @JanDvorak: That exists?

Comment: @minitech yup. Prefixed pretty much everywhere, but still better in terms of compatibility than mutation events (since both Chrome and Firefox support them)

Comment: I'm afraid mutation events don't fire during initial load.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Are you saying mutation observers can’t be used, or are mutation events what Matt Ball linked to, and they’re two different things? Or answering your initial question? :D

Comment: @minitech My initial question was written under the condition I was not aware of the asker's ultimate desires. Now that I am, I have to state that mutation observers _can't_ be used, since the element comes to existence during the initial load. (if I understand the question correctly).